# C++ Iterator do what?

Tags: c++, iterator

Code:

```
  vector<weight *> &res;
  vector<weight>::iterator it = lower_bound(w.begin(), w.end(), queryweight);
  while(it != w.end()) {
      weight *w  = &(*it);
      if(w->weight >= 60) break;
      res.push_back(w);
      it++;
  }
```

I think the `lower_bound` do a binary search (?), so in the end, does the C++ code intend to get the weights wanted? Where it starts and stops? And what does the `while` loop in this case do? thanks!

Comment: `vector<weight *> &res;` wouldn't compile, as references need to be initialized.

Comment: @sbi, look, why C++ has such bunch of stranger notes? so messy

Comment: @ladyfafa: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479731/codingbat-like-site-for-c/3480268#3480268) for a recent rant of mine about C++' complexity. Really, believe what [I told you in a comment yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480320/what-does-the-mean-in-c/3480333#3480333) and pick up a beginner's C++ book.

Comment: @sbi: thanks for the comment, i really did some google search and check the c++ reference, give me some time plesae

Comment: @Stephen: what is a green tick? (sorry, iam new here, knows little about the rules,haha)

Comment: @sbi: What is the difference between "vector<weight *>" and "vector<weight>" exactly?

Comment: @ladyfafa `vector<weight *>` is a vector of [pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) to weight objects. `vector<weight>` is a vector of weight objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lower_bound` returns the lowest iterator (i.e. position in the vector) of an element that is **not** less than the third parameter - here, `queryweight`. The `while` loop then goes through the remaining elements and, until it reaches an element that has a `wight` of greater than or equal to 60 adds them to the vector `res`. I assume the input vector `w` is sorted, otherwise this function wouldn't make much sense.

Line by line:

```
// Declare a vector of pointers to 'weight' objects, called res.
// (I assume here that the "&" in the original question was a mistake.)
vector<weight *> res;

// Find the iterator that points to the lowest element in vector 'w'
// such that the element is >= queryweight.
vector<weight>::iterator it = lower_bound(w.begin(), w.end(), queryweight);

// From this element forwards until the end of vector 'w'
while(it != w.end()) {
    // Get a pointer to the element.
    weight *w  = &(*it);
    // If the 'wight' property of this element is >= 60, stop.
    if(w->wight >= 60) break;
    // Push the element onto the 'res' vector.
    res.push_back(w);
    // Move to the next element.
    it++;
}
```

Comment: @Stephen: the sorted vector is from lowest to highest? or in the opposite?

Comment: See sbi's comment on the question.

Comment: @Stephen, well i think it's better be "weight" property, spelling errors sorry

Comment: @Stephen: JFTR, I didn't consider your oversight of the `&` bad enough to down-vote your answer.

Comment: @Stephen: Okay, I green ticked you

Comment: @Stephen: I just noticed the downvote issues, take it easy~~~